# Javascript Clipboard API no me escribe en el portapapeles en Safari 15.3

Tags: javascript

El siguiente código usando Javascript Clipboard API no me funciona en Safari 15.3.

```
    var copyText = document.getElementById("inpprov");
    copyText.value = "Cualquier texto";
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
    navigator.clipboard
   .writeText(copyText.value)
       .then(() => {
           console.log("successfully copied");
            })
       .catch(() => {
           console.log("something went wrong");
         });
```

He dado el valor de "Cualquier texto" a la propiedad *value* de copyText. En el caso real esa propiedad lleva un texto HTML bastante largo. Lo comento por si la causa del problema fuese esa.

El código se ejecuta en una función Javascript como respuesta al evento *click* de usuario de un elemento *button*. En esa función Javascript hay llamadas a métodos del servidor con "<%%>" alojados en una clase. ¿En este caso es factible el uso de la Javascript Clipboard API?

¿Alguien podría decirme si ve algo incorrecto?

Comment: En IOS solo está disponible en conexiones seguras o localhost, estás probando el código en una página con https?

Comment: Hola! Pues sí, el sitio es https://. Gracias!

Comment: podría ayudarte a saber el error si cambias el `catch` por `.catch(alert)`

Comment: Hice una prueba para que el usuario que está usando Safari visualizara el mensaje "something went wrong" si no se copiaba. Le puse alert("something went wrong") y efectivamente se mostró ese mensaje

Comment: Podrías escribirme cómo sería? Hace muy poco que usos Promises.

Comment: Claro, pero antes, puedes intentar esto en tu celular? `alert(navigator.clipboard)`, puede que salga `undefined`

Comment: El problema es que yo trabajo en Windows 10 y la persona que hace las pruebas en Safari ya ha ha hecho varias. Si no tengo algo que crea que va a funcionar no me gustaría molestarla. En la próxima prueba que haga lo pondré así y a ver que texto muestra.

Comment: Lo pruebo en mi móvil, pero es Android!

Comment: En mi móvil es imposible probarlo porque Safari no es compatible con Android

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134240/discussion-between-brayan-martinez-santana-and-manuel-cera).